# How to make a synchronization mutex with access by every process?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, synchronization, mutex

I need to use a global mutex to synchronize access to a mutually shared file by several processes. I create the mutex as such:

```
HANDLE hMutex = ::CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, L"Global\\MySpecialName");
```

And then use it in:

```
//Entering critical section
VERIFY(::WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0);
```

and then:

```
//Leave critical section
VERIFY(::ReleaseMutex(hMutex));
```

The issue arises from the fact that the processes sharing this mutex are a local-system service and several user-mode processes running with credentials of a logged on user. So if the mutex is first created by the service, then when the user-mode process tries to open it, `CreateMutex` fails with error code `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

I was reading into specifying a security descriptor for the mutex before creating it but I can't seem to figure out how to make it accessible by `everything`, I don't really need any complexity here?

Comment: See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446595(v=vs.85).aspx) for an example of creating a security descriptor that grants read access to everyone.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I think came across something like that. You see the issue is this line `One ACE allows read access to everyone` -- in my case I need full access for everyone, because I'm also synchronizing against the mutex.

Comment: Also `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` won't apply in my case. What do I need instead for a mutex -- `FILE_ALL_ACCESS` or `GENERIC_ALL`?

Comment: Full access for everyone is a mighty unwise idea if you ask me, for something that is owned and used by a local-system service. Unless security doesn't matter at all, of course. Read access for anyone is already somewhat problematic, because _anyone_ could block the service simply by waiting on the mutex. Eventually, sooner or later, the attacker will acquire the mutex. So he never releases it, what now? The service is blocked forever. But given write access, someone could e.g. close the handle. If your process isn't prepared for that, it may abort with an exception.

Comment: @Damon: OK, how would you implement interprocess synchronization to a shared resource then?

Comment: It's a tough challenge, admittedly. At least for syncing the clients with the service, a semaphore or an event might be a better choice (global readonly). That way the worst thing someone can do is also wait on the sync, but it can't block the service forever or close the handle. The other way around is hard... if it is really necessary that user programs can block the service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I use, based on [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20151215210112/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/11/10/access-denied-on-a-mutex.aspx):

```
HANDLE hMutex = NULL;
DWORD dwError;

// Create a global mutex
pSecDesc = MakeAllowAllSecurityDescriptor();
if(pSecDesc)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES SecAttr;
    SecAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    SecAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = pSecDesc;
    SecAttr.bInheritHandle = FALSE;
    
    hMutex = CreateMutex(&SecAttr, TRUE, MUTEX_NAME);
    dwError = GetLastError();
    LocalFree(pSecDesc);
}
```

...

```
//
// From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/11/10/access-denied-on-a-mutex.aspx
//
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR MakeAllowAllSecurityDescriptor(void)
{
    WCHAR *pszStringSecurityDescriptor;
    if(GetWindowsVersion(NULL) >= 6)
        pszStringSecurityDescriptor = L"D:(A;;GA;;;WD)(A;;GA;;;AN)S:(ML;;NW;;;ME)";
    else
        pszStringSecurityDescriptor = L"D:(A;;GA;;;WD)(A;;GA;;;AN)";
    
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSecDesc;
    if(!ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(pszStringSecurityDescriptor, SDDL_REVISION_1, &pSecDesc, NULL))
        return NULL;
    
    return pSecDesc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what `D:(A;;GA;;;WD)(A;;GA;;;AN)S:(ML;;NW;;;ME)` translates into?

Comment: It's all said in the article. "D:(A;;GA;;;WD)(A;;GA;;;AN)S:(ML;;NW;;;ME) -> for medium integrity".

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. I'm trying to understand what all these crazy symbols mean "D:(A;;GA;;;WD)(A;;GA;;;AN)S:(ML;;NW;;;ME"?

Comment: You can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Sorry. I tried your method and it didn't work if I make my user-mode process run with `SECURITY_MANDATORY_LOW_RID`. I still get `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` from `CreateMutex`

Comment: OK, I had to do this that worked `D:(A;;GA;;;WD)(A;;GA;;;AN)S:(ML;;;;;S-1-16-0)`